# I can't stop postgresql server on ssh with Jenkins

Tags: bash, postgresql, jenkins, ssh, pg-ctl

I try to do some actions on my Postgresql sever and I restart it...

I'm doing that with a Jenkins job, so I use script from my Jenkins machine who connect on ssh to the postgresql server. But problem, it display me this since 2hours

[image: restart postgresql waiting]

and when I try to restart it directly in the commandline in the postgresql machine it works

I dot that like this in the Build step of the jenkins job
[image: ssh command from jenkins]

How can resolve it please ?

Comment: Can you show the script and how it's being called from Jenkins?

Comment: ah sure, I have edited the question @nitind